# Components not spanning a split cell in Miglayout

Tags: java, miglayout

I have read the Miglayout Quick Start Guide and White Paper. I'm trying to lay out the dialog so that all of the checkboxes are aligned in two columns, even though they are sometimes separated by radiobuttons.

I would like the text field and the separator to span the width of the dialog, while still being next to their label. The text area should also be on its own line. I have tried splitting the first column and that accomplishes the proper spacing, however, the components don't "span" to the next column, even with the keyword.

I thought this should be possible, because of the quick start guide saying,

> "It is of course possible to both span and split cells at the same time."

(Pg 2)

Complete code example is below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snack Selection");

    JTextField d_msrField = new JTextField("Jane Doe");
    d_msrField.setEnabled(false);
    d_msrField.setColumns(30);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug, wrap 2", "[]15[]"));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"), "gapbottom 11, gaptop 11, split 2");
    panel.add(d_msrField, "span 2");

    panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Fruit"), "wrap");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Apple"), "gapleft 18");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Orange"));
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Pear"), "gapleft 18");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Banana"));
    panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Vegetable"), "wrap");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Celery"), "gapleft 18");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Carrot"));
    panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Dairy Item"), "wrap");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Milk"), "gapleft 18");
    panel.add(new JCheckBox("Cheese"));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Options"), "split 2");
    panel.add(new JSeparator(), "span 2, growx");

    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    JScrollPane opts = new JScrollPane(ta);
    panel.add(opts, "gapleft 18");

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: dialog image]

EDIT: To fix the problem, I've added an extra column at the beginning and "wrap 3", but I'm still curious if anyone knows why the original code didn't work.

[image: fixed dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you sorted it with `wrap 3` but I think your main issue was how you used `split, span`.

For example, if you look at the first lines where you add something to your panel

```
panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"), "gapbottom 11, gaptop 11, split 2");
panel.add(d_msrField, "span 2");
```

Here you `split` the first cell (this essentially makes that cell a sub row within a grid) and then try to `span` when you add `d_msrField`. The issue there is `d_msrField` is already the last cell in this `sub row` so span won't do anything.

What you actually need to do is span the `sub row`.

```
panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"), "gapbottom 11, gaptop 11, split, span");
```

You have the same issue with the JSeparator.

If you apply this principle of splitting and then spanning the first cell what you have works as expected.

[image]

---

**Runnable Example**

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snack Selection");

        JTextField d_msrField = new JTextField("Jane Doe");
        d_msrField.setEnabled(false);
        d_msrField.setColumns(30);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[]15[grow]"));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"), "gapbottom 11, gaptop 11, split, span");
        panel.add(d_msrField, "wrap");

        panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Fruit"), "wrap, span");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Apple"), "gapleft 18");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Orange"));
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Pear"), "gapleft 18");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Banana"));
        panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Vegetable"), "span, wrap");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Celery"), "gapleft 18");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Carrot"));
        panel.add(new JRadioButton("Choose a Dairy Item"), "span, wrap");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Milk"), "gapleft 18");
        panel.add(new JCheckBox("Cheese"));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Options"), "split, span");
        panel.add(new JSeparator(), "gaptop 4, growx, wrap");

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        JScrollPane opts = new JScrollPane(ta);
        panel.add(opts, "gapleft 18, span, growx");

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

*Sub row may or may not be the right terminology but it was a descriptive term I made up to try and help answer the question*